# rake:test not running custom tests in subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, testunit, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0.0.beta1. I added two directories: `app/services` and `test/services`.

I also added this code, based on reading [testing.rake of railties](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0.beta1/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake):

```
namespace :test do
  Rake::TestTask.new(services: "test:prepare") do |t|
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/services/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end
```

I have found that `rake test:services` runs the tests in `test/services`; however, `rake test` does not run those tests. It looks like it *should*; here is the [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0.beta1/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L75):

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:all) do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.pattern = "test/**/*_test.rb"
end
```

Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a line like this after your test task definition:

```
Rake::Task[:test].enhance { Rake::Task["test:services"].invoke }
```

I don't know why they're not automatically getting picked up, but this is the only solution I've found that works for Test::Unit.

I think if you were to run `rake test:all` it would run your additional tests, but `rake test` alone won't without the snippet above.

Comment: Re: "I don't know why they're not automatically getting picked up" -- I don't know if this is intentional, or just an asymmetry that developed as changes were made. So I added a [comment on the pull request that added the test:all task](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9177#issuecomment-14575192).

Answer (score 4):

For those using a more recent Rails version (4.1.0 in my case)

Use `Rails::TestTask` instead of `Rake::TestTask` and override `run` task:

```
namespace :test do
  task :run => ['test:units', 'test:functionals', 'test:generators', 'test:integration', 'test:services']
  Rails::TestTask.new(services: "test:prepare") do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/services/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Jim's solution works, however it ends up running the extra test suite as a separate task and not as part of the whole (at least using Rails 4.1 it does). So test stats are run twice rather than aggregated. I don't feel this is the desired behaviour here.

This is how I ended up solving this (using Rails 4.1.1)

```
# Add additional test suite definitions to the default test task here

namespace :test do
  Rails::TestTask.new(extras: "test:prepare") do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/extras/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end

Rake::Task[:test].enhance ['test:extras']
```

This results in exactly expected behaviour by simply including the new `test:extras` task in the set of tasks executed by `rake test` and of course the default `rake`. You can use this approach to add any number of new test suites this way.

If you are using Rails 3 I believe just changing to `Rake::TestTask` will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Or simply run `rake test:all`

If you want to run all tests by default, override test task:

```
namespace :test do
  task run: ['test:all']
end
```